# VirtualBox Ubuntu screen not achieving 1920x1080 while window achieves 1920x1080

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution, desktop

This is an instance of a newly-installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

The window resized successfully. The desktop background did not follow suit. An image of the situation is below. Any ideas for a fix? Thank you!

[image: VirtualBox resizes. The Ubuntu desktop background does not.]

Comment: See in VBOX if you can View - Fit Guest?   That is how I do it in VMware.

Comment: There is an, "Auto-resize to Guest Display," option which, when clicked, did not do anything.

Comment: Make sure you have VBOX Essential Tools installed in the Guest. Restart after installing.

Comment: I did install all Guest Additions and restarted. This screenshot was taken after both actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case of running Ubuntu22.04 from Windows10 I fixed this problem by changing the graphic controller in settings to VBoxVGA.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question. I found that a reinstallation of the Ubuntu ISO and resizing the virtual partition occupying the Ubuntu.vdi file in Windows fixed these problems. Ubuntu runs smoothly on all graphics controllers now. Thank you for suggesting the Guest Additions-compatible graphics controller.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Try to enable 3D acceleration. That fixed my issue.